# unable to click Launch Plesk in godaddy

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, godaddy-api

unable to click launch plesk in godaddy.

it looks like disabled. and the below CPU are loading. because of this my website is not opening. I don't have any idea about this. can anyone suggest what issue is this? I am new to word press and web hosting. thanks in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em4Vx.jpg)guide me to clear the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to contact your hosting provider regarding this issue. If you are unable to login to their Plesk, it might be that the server is overload or traffic is high on control panel.